# UI Integration sample required of Spring Security Plugin of Grails

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have been working with grails application and for security purpose used the spring security core.

Now with that they are also providing the UI stuffs of security. So I have installed the plugin from http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui in the project where I have configured spring security core too.

Now I have not found any videocast or any sample links where I can find that how can it be configured with my existing project.

So want some sample application or links so that I can get the spring security ui working in my project.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try the online documentation? It is very thorough

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/tree/master/src/docs/guide

Answer (score 4):

Burt's docs are indeed excellent (code too, BTW, if anyone's counting). But it's not actually all that obvious how to integrate the Grails Spring Security UI plugin. Try this recipe (tested with Grails 1.3.5):

1. **Don't** download the grails-contacts ZIP file described in the Grails Spring Security ACL plugin documentation
2. Get the sample application using `git clone http://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-acl.git` instead. That gives you a list of the links to the controllers you need. Trust me: you want to do this.
3. Do a `grails upgrade` and say yes to everything
4. The ACL demo app should run as-is with `grails run-app`
5. Upgrade the spring-security-core plugin: say `grails install-plugin spring-security-core`
6. Now the spring-security-acl plugin with `grails install-plugin spring-security-acl`
7. Now what you wanted all along, `grails install-plugin spring-security-ui`
8. And try `grails run-app`
9. Don't see the controllers you're after? You probably have the ZIP file and not the latest git clone.

Please let me know how you make out.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from official docs which Aaron already posted, I also found this tutorial: [Customizing The Grails Spring Security UI Plugin](http://www.objectpartners.com/2011/05/24/customizing-the-grails-spring-security-ui-plugin/) useful.